# Conjectured Cauchy principal value for Goodwin-Staton integral

Tags: integration, special-functions, cauchy-principal-value

In an answer to [Goodwin Staton integral $G(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t^2}}{t+x}dt$ and its symmetry](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2393095/61216) I conjectured
$$PV \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t^2}}{t+x}dt =
\sqrt{\pi} F(x) - \frac{1}{2} e^{-x^2}\mathrm{Ei}(x^2)\quad (x\ne 0)\quad(*)$$
where $F(x)$ is the [Dawson integral](http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.2.ii) and
$\mathrm{Ei}(x)$ the [exponential integral](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2.E5). This is an extension of http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.5.E13 to negative $x.$

> Is there a rigorous proof for formula (*)?

I checked it numerically with the QUADPACK integration routine QAWC (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUADPACK), which computes the Cauchy principal value of the integral of $f(x)/(x–c)$ for user-specified $c$ and $f$ and got the same results with $15$ digits:

```
   x            (*)                     QAWC
-10.00    -0.094123656234351    -0.094123656234351
 -9.00    -0.105340117792338    -0.105340117792338
 -8.00    -0.119603520771815    -0.119603520771815
 -7.00    -0.138358842389358    -0.138358842389358
 -6.00    -0.164146157367184    -0.164146157367184
 -5.00    -0.201901172247312    -0.201901172247312
 -4.00    -0.262774143418388    -0.262774143418388
 -3.00    -0.380019352972186    -0.380019352972186
 -2.00    -0.713887936713151    -0.713887936713151
 -1.00    -1.302308535738411    -1.302308535738411
  1.00     0.605133652503345     0.605133652503345
  2.00     0.354335928849531     0.354335928849531
  3.00     0.251934996448972     0.251934996448972
  4.00     0.195752582376989     0.195752582376989
  5.00     0.160154694796648     0.160154694796648
  6.00     0.135549871910491     0.135549871910491
  7.00     0.117516050600851     0.117516050600851
  8.00     0.103726368842216     0.103726368842216
  9.00     0.092838112910918     0.092838112910918
 10.00     0.084021593706602     0.084021593706602
```

Comment: This is the Mellin convolution of $\exp(-t^2)$ and $\frac1{1+t}$. Thus, you can take the Mellin transforms of these two, multiply those and express fully as gamma functions, and then invert the transform.

Comment: @j-m-isnt-a-mathematician: I am not familiar with Mellin transforms. Using your comment, the table from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MellinTransform.html, and the Gamma reflection
formula I get
$$MT\left(e^{-t^2}\right)MT\left(\frac{1}{1+t}\right)=\pi \csc\left(\pi z\right)\times \frac{1}{2}
\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}z\right)=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}z\right)
\Gamma\left(z\right)\Gamma\left(1-z\right).$$ But how do I get the inverse transform and how does this prove the PV formula?

Comment: After converting the $\Gamma\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)$, you should now be able to get a corresponding Meijer $G$ expression that should reduce to a hypergeometric case, since the functions in the closed form are hypergeometric. Anyway, that was only an idea; there is possibly a simpler route.

Comment: @j-m-is-not-a-mathematician: I think I found another route, would you please have a look on my answer. Are there irreparable errors?

Comment: You will like the question (and hopefully the answers) here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412761/another-integral-related-to-fresnel-integrals/1417077#1417077

Comment: @tired: Thank you! Interesting answer and link to a great paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Table_of_selected_Hilbert_transforms),
the Hilbert transform of $e^{-t^2}$ is 
$$\frac{1}{\pi} PV \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-t^2}}{x-t}dt =    2\pi^{-1/2} F(x).$$
Assume $x<0$. Then we have
$$ 2\sqrt{\pi} F(x) = PV \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-t^2}}{x-t}dt =
PV \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{e^{-t^2}}{x-t}dt + 
PV \int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-t^2}}{x-t}dt=\\
PV \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{e^{-t^2}}{x-t}dt - 
PV \int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-t^2}}{t-x}dt=
PV \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{e^{-t^2}}{x-t}dt 
- G(-x)
$$
Substitution $t\rightarrow -t$ and reversing limits of integration gives
$$
PV \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{e^{-t^2}}{x-t}dt =
-PV \int_{\infty}^0 \frac{e^{-t^2}}{x+t}dt =
PV \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t^2}}{x+t}dt
$$
and therefore
$$ 2\sqrt{\pi} F(x) = PV \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t^2}}{x+t}dt - G(-x)$$

Then (*) follows from the fact that $F(x)$ is odd:
$$PV \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t^2}}{x+t}dt
=2\sqrt{\pi} F(x) +G(-x)
= 2\sqrt{\pi} F(x) + \sqrt{\pi} F(-x)- \frac{1}{2} e^{-x^2}\mathrm{Ei}(x^2)\\
=\sqrt{\pi} F(x)  - \frac{1}{2} e^{-x^2}\mathrm{Ei}(x^2)
$$

Comment: I didn't have a Hilbert transform table on hand, but this looks quite clean!

Comment: @j-m-is-not-a-mathematician: Many thanks for your effort!